# Fail Result for teststepwarning in CANoE, CAPL

Tags: capl, canoe

I am a beginner in CAPL. I wanted to differentiate the testcases with warnings and testcases that are passed in the overview section of the report.

i.e. If the test case produces a warning (testcasewarning) then is it possible to make it appear on the overall test results section.

Is it possible to configure some xslt or xml file to do this.??

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function CAPL function

```
TestStepWarning ()
```

or any of its variants from CAPL Test Feature Set for this. The verdict of the corresponding testcase will still be PASS but in the HTML report there will be a yellow marking indicating the warning.

Answer (score -1):

In the system folder of your CANOE installation you should be able to find a document with the extension onepage.xslt. If you did not change the default settings in your test module options the onepage.xslt is used to generate the *.html report from the *.xml file.

You can change the style the *.html report looks like by changing this file. (You can also include more jscripts here for fancy stuff)